# Filling model with data when passing it as an method argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there possible to do something like that:

```
    // GET:/Person/5
    public ActionResult ShowDetails(Person p)
    {
        // There shoud be object filled with data from database, something like that:
        // p.id = 5, p.Name = "John" (person of id 5 has name "John" in database)
        return View(p);
    }
```

Shoud i use ModelBinders for that? If yes can i do one model binder that will be fetching data for any model? Ive already done model binder for Person, but i dont know how to do that to work with multiple models. Thank you.

Comment: Is the `DbContext` in a `using` statement? Where is the `DbContext` constructed?

Comment: I dont want to fetch data in ShowDetails method, i want model binder to do that.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. The answers are: Yes, it is possible. No, IMO, you should not fetch data in a ModelBinder. If you do, you can certainly register a single generic ModelBinder to multiple model types. All that being said, there are many problems with accessing the database in a place of the MVC pipeline that is designed for mapping properties to and from HTML. You will spend a lot of time and effort trying to force MVC to do something that isn't baked into the design.

Comment: @user1652792: Why? That's what your controller action is *for*: fetch anything that needs to be fetched and pass it on to the view. Any time you're having to fight this hard against the framework, that's a sign that what you're doing is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @ChrisPratt 
Thanks, actually you're right. I'll simply fetch data in controller.